# zsh_history just showing few entries and not all

Tags: debian, zsh, command-history

I don't know why but .zsh_history only shows a few entries and not all.

```
shirish@debian ~ % history       
  155  zless changelog.Debian.gz
  156* torbrowser-launcher
  157* apt-cache rdepends libsdl1.2debian
  158* hg clone https://bitbucket.org/allacrost/allacrost
  160  cd Videos
  161  history | grep apg
  162  history | less
```

This is what is in .zshrc -

```
% cat .zshrc
# Set up the prompt

autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit
prompt adam1

setopt histignorealldups sharehistory

# Use emacs keybindings even if our EDITOR is set to vi
bindkey -e

# Keep 10000 lines of history within the shell and save it to ~/.zsh_history:
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history

# Use modern completion system
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' auto-description 'specify: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt %SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true

zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=0=01;31'
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*' command 'ps -u $USER -o pid,%cpu,tty,cputime,cmd'
```

I do have several tabs of the VTE (Virtual Terminal Emulator) or zsh open. Maybe I'm missing a trick or something.

Except for the change in number of entries to be kept on record, all others the default values.

I am on Debian testing and using zsh version -

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)
```

Update - This is what it says -

```
 ~ % ls -l ~/.zsh_history
-rw------- 1 shirish shirish 6451 Jan  5 20:59 /home/shirish/.zsh_history
```

Comment: Is `.zsh_history` writable? What is the output of `ls -l ~/.zsh_history` ?

Comment: @baselab, have updated my query with the answer you asked for.

Comment: What is your basis for saying that it shows only a few entries and not all — what were you expecting, and why? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Is this about the commands from 1 through 154, or 159?

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh`, `history` does not (and not supposed to) show by default everything you have in `.zsh_history`, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/160342/zsh-only-displaying-last-16-or-so-commands-with-history-histsize-savehist-are/): it shows only last 15 commands (7 in your case for some reason). To show everything, you'd rather type `history 1`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846738/zsh-history-is-too-short).